# Deleting text from .txt file from within R

Tags: r

I have some code which appends text over an existing `.txt` file , from within `R` as following :

```
write("puts 'hellow world '", file = "C:\\Ruby22-x64\\bin\\elt.rb",
      append = TRUE, sep = " ")
setwd("C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/")
test<-system("ruby elt.rb",intern=TRUE) # this will return "hellow world" from ruby interpreter
```

My question is: after appending the `.rb` file and running it, how can i remove the *"puts 'hellow world '"* string from the `.rb` file, and return it to its initial state?

I tried to look for many functions, but couldn't find any function which can undo the `write` function.

Comment: One way would be to first copy the original file to some other place and then replace the modified file by the copy of the original, once you are done.

Comment: My initial thought is to use sed from within R. You may be able to call it with system(), although I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out a wonderful gist that does the Job : https://gist.github.com/mages/1544009

gist:1544009

Comment: Please include the gist here as links to external sources may go offline without notice.